# Altering View in MS SQL Server by Adding Col based on Join

Tags: sql-server

I have created a view that queries a table called Sheet1$. It has a carID field, and a carName field.

So I created my view by doing the following:

```
CREATE VIEW corvettes 
AS
SELECT *
FROM Sheet1$ 
WHERE carName = 'corvette'
```

I have another table called Sheet2. It has a carID field, and a carYear field. I want to alter my original view by adding a COL to it called YEAR and then populate YEAR with the values of Sheet2$.carYear via join of the two carID fields.

I can get the YEAR field appended with the correct data, but if there is no match of the ID's, then the whole row goes away. I'd rather have the YEAR say NULL instead of going away if the ID's don't match.

This is what I have. Where am I going wrong?

```
ALTER VIEW corvettes 
AS
SELECT a.carID, a.carName, b.carYear 
FROM Sheet1$ a, Sheet2$ b 
WHERE a.carID = b.carID 
AND carName = 'corvette'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as some cars has not Year, you should use a LEFT JOIN on this way:

```
ALTER VIEW corvettes 
AS
SELECT    a.carID, a.carName, b.carYear 
FROM      Sheet1$ a
LEFT JOIN Sheet2$ b 
ON        a.carID = b.carID 
WHERE     a.carName = 'corvette'
```

Have a look at [Using OUTER JOINS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) at Microsoft Docs.